# Vuex vuejs nodejs maintaining and storing multiple connections to an API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vuex

I'm a Vue beginner writing an app that manages multiple devices of the same type. Each device needs to connection to an API in order to perform any request. **How do I maintain and store this connection so I do not have to attempt to connect before every request?**

At the moment I only have Vuex and Vuejs for my app and every time the user needs to perform an action on the device, I connect the device, execute the request and disconnect the device. This is obviously very inefficient. I want to make my Vue app maintain a continuous connection and only disconnect when the device is manually removed from the app or when the app closes.
Here is an example of what I'm currently doing:

```
(async () => {
    await device.find();
    await device.connect();
    await device.execute(action)
    device.disconnect();
})();
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For long contiuous connections, use sockets. socket.io is an excellent solution but that isn't native sockets.

Comment: I thought about sockets too. It would work perfectly I think. I'm thinking I would create a socket for each device. But I'm not sure how I would go about managing the connection and then retrieving the connection from the backend from Vuex/Vuejs

Comment: Umm? Sockets are a connection

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should start using sockets for such scenarios.

---

Using socket.io with Vue.js and Node.js full example:

In your backend (Node.js):

```
//setting up sockets
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('executeAction', function(data) {
    io.emit('updateSomeData', data)
  });
})
```

---

Sending an update from the Vue component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

data() {
 return {
  socket: io(),
  someData: []
 }
},
methods: {
 this.socket.emit('executeAction', {someData: this.someData})
}
```

---

Listening to socket in the Vue component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

data() {
 return {
  socket: io(),
  someData: []
 }
},
created() {
  this.socket.on('updateSomeData', (data) => {
   this.someData = data.someData
  })
}
```

---

For your reference: [socket.io](https://socket.io/)